# Returning multiple diffrerent rows in a TableView while looping through an array

Tags: swift

I would like to populate so many rows in a tableview as I have entries defined. At my actual code I receive only the first item.

What I expect is to have all 3 countries populated.

my code looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// How many sections. Means numberOfSections * rows = view
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// Defines the number of rows in a section table
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 1
}

// Defines contet of each cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell

    var countries =  ["Turkey","Croatia","USA"]

    var logoImageTUR = UIImage(named: "turkey.png")
    var logoimageCRO =  UIImage(named: "croatia.png")
    var logoimageUSA = UIImage(named: "USA.png")

    var countryLogos = [logoImageTUR, logoimageCRO, logoimageUSA]

    for var i = 0; i < 2; i++
    {
        cell.lbl_countryName.text = countries[i]
        cell.img_countryFlag.image = countryLogos[i]

        return cell
    }
}
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your two list outside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and update the `numberOfRowsInSection` and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like in the following way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   var countries =  ["Turkey","Croatia","USA"]    
   var countryLogos = [UIImage(named: "turkey.png"), UIImage(named: "croatia.png"), UIImage(named: "USA.png") ]

   // Defines the number of rows in a section table
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
      return countries.count
   }

   // Defines content of each cell
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell

     // Populates with the indexPath.row according the position inside the list
     cell.lbl_countryName.text = countries[indexPath.row]
     cell.img_countryFlag.image = countryLogos[indexPath.row]

     return cell    
   }

   // Rest of code...

}
```

It should do what you want.

In the above code put only the code relevant to your question, you need the rest of your code to work, I mean the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` , etc. You need too implements the two protocols `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` or define a `UITableViewController` using Storyboards by the way.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Defines the number of rows in a section table
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 1
}
```

Your data source reports that the table contains only a single row.

Comment: while increasing this value to 3 I receive just 3 times the the same entry. Means 3 rows turkey,turkey,turkey. And not 3 different entries like turkey, croatia, USA

Comment: Yes, look at your `for var i = 0; i < 2; i++` loop. You set the name and flag of a cell to the first value in `countries` and `countryLogos` and then you set replace the name and flag of the _same cell_ with the second value from those array, and again for the third. You never consider the row of the provided index path when populating the cell.